# set column name and column width using PHPExcel in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

Good day, I'm struggling to find out how to set a column name before each value in PHPExcel with codeigniter. Since my PHPExcel works to get the value from database, my problem is how to set a column name of each column.

current output image:

[image]

My code:

```
       //load our new PHPExcel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        //activate worksheet number 1
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        //name the worksheet
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Users list');

        // Trying to set a column name
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'ID');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'FIRST NAME');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'LAST NAME');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'EMAIL');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'TIME');
        // get all users in array formate
        $users = $this->User_info->getallusers();


        // read data to active sheet
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($users);

        $filename='just_some_random_name.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name

        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

        //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
        //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');

        //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
                ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I want the output look like this

[image]

One more problem that I've seen is the width of every column. can you fix it also for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($users);
```

The default top-left cell for the `fromArray()` method is cell `A1`, and it will overwrite anything that is already in cell `A1`.... if you want to avoid overwriting the headers that you have already set in row 1, then you'll need to tell `fromArray()` to start at row 2, so the top-left cell will be `A2`

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($users, null, 'A2');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution for export excel.

```
//load our new PHPExcel library
$this->load->library('excel');
//activate worksheet number 1
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//name the worksheet
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Users list');

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);


$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:E1")->applyFromArray(array("font" => array("bold" => true)));

$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'FIRST NAME');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'LAST NAME');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D1', 'EMAIL ADDRESS');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E1', 'TIME');

// get all users in array formate
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($users, null, 'A2');

// read data to active sheet
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($users);

$filename='just_some_random_name.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');

//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
        ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

you can add more style for heading column using **applyFromArray**.

Comment: sir @Nikunk Rathod, you fixed the column width and the font-weight of the first row, your code help me to understand the problem.. but can I ask you again sir, why it is no field name appears since I put this code 

 $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'FIRST NAME');
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'LAST NAME');
.....

Comment: the Field Name: ID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, EMAIL, TIME does not appear in the first row of the table...

Comment: you can put this line **ob_end_clean();** above in $objWriter Object.

Comment: sir @Nikunji ob_end_clean(); is already exist in my code.  please look at the end line before the objwriter